# How do I display currency in a Flask Table generated table column?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

flask-table does have several specific column types. For example date: DateCol. But there is no column type for currency. So for now data is displayed using the standard Col type. Now you just get a Decimal. It works but I'd would prefer a currency format.

Table.py

```
# import things
from flask_table import Table, Col, DateCol

# Declare my table
class MyTable(Table):
    classes = ['table', 'table-hover']
    id = Col('id')
    amount = Col('amount')
    date = DateCol('date')
```

template.html

```
<div>{{ amounts_table }}</div>
```

routes.py

```
@route('/my_table')
def my_table():
    table_content = Amounts.query.all()
    amounts_table = AmountsTable(table_content)
    return render_template('template.html', amounts_table=amounts_table)
```

result:

```
id     amount       date
1      1,523.78     30-03-2019
```

what I would like to accomplish:

```
id     amount       date
1      € 1.523,78   30-03-2019
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [subclass the `Col` class](https://flask-table.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#subclassing-col).

Assuming your `amount` data is stored as a string (such as `1,523.78`), you could do something like this:

```
# Python 3.7

import locale

class CurrencyCol(Col):
    def td_format(self, content):
        amount = float(content.replace(',', ''))
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'nl_NL')
        val = locale.format_string('%.2f', float(amount), 1, 1).replace(' ', '.')
        return f'€ {val}'
```

Then change your table to use the new `CurrencyCol`:

```
class MyTable(Table):
    classes = ['table', 'table-hover']
    id = Col('id')
    amount = CurrencyCol('amount')
    date = DateCol('date')
```

Comment: wow, didn't know this would be so simple, I'm loving python more by the day. Thanks @atwalsh!